# Using Dart googleapis_auth (0.2.2) to authorize Admin SDK Directory API in Google Apps domains with service account

Tags: dart, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I would like to authorize access to Admin SDK Directory API in Google Apps domains with a service account. As I understand it requires a [JWT claim with a sub field](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and I can't find that in the pub package [googleapis_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis_auth) (0.2.2).

If it's missing:

Is there a workaround?
Will it be included in a future version?

For the time being I'm getting along with an installed app authorizing with user consent (admin account) but it's a bit tedious...

Comment: Maybe you can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_jwt (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_auth_session uses it for example)

Comment: Google Apps requires a sub field in the claim set, containing the email address of an administrator. I can't find a way to include that in this package either. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks

Comment: You are not missing anything. The creation for service account credentials does not support setting the user to impersonate and populate the sub field in the claim. I have filed [issue 15](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth/issues/15)

Comment: @sgjesse Turns out there's a fork for this: https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth/issues/14 Works like a breeze :)

Comment: This is now supported in version 0.2.3 of `googleapis_auth`. See answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 0.2.3 of `googleapis_auth` the constructors for `ServiceAccountCredentials` have the optional named argument `impersonatedUser` which can be used to set the user to impersonate.

The code for listing all users using the Admin SDK Directory API in Google Apps domains with a service account, on behalf of the admin user *admin@domain.com* looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:googleapis/admin/directory_v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v2.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

final credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
  "private_key_id": "<please fill in>",
  "private_key": "<please fill in>",
  "client_email": "<please fill in>",
  "client_id": "<please fill in>",
  "type": "service_account"
}, user: 'admin@domain.com');

const SCOPES = const [AdminApi.AdminDirectoryGroupScope,
                      AdminApi.AdminDirectoryUserScope];
void main() {
  clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, SCOPES).then((http_client) {
    var admin = new AdminApi(http_client);
    admin.users.list(domain: 'domain.com').then((Users users) {
      users.users.forEach((user) => print(user.name.fullName));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm now using googleapis_auth 0.2.3 and it works fine. I believe your code example should be "impersonatedUser: 'admin@domain.com'" Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is supported as described in https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth#autonomous-application--service-account. With version 0.2.3 the constructors for `ServiceAccountCredentials` now have the optional named argument `impersonatedUser` which can be used to set the user to impersonate.

```dart
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart";

var accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
  "private_key_id": "<please fill in>",
  "private_key": "<please fill in>",
  "client_email": "<please fill in>@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<please fill in>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}, impersonatedUser: 'user@domain.com');
var scopes = [...];

...

var client = new http.Client();
obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes, client)
    .then((AccessCredentials credentials) {
  // Access credentials are available in [credentials].
  // ...
  client.close();
});
```

Comment: Google Apps requires a sub field in the claim set, containing the email address of an administrator. I can't find a way to include that in googleapis_auth. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks

Comment: I believe Google requires `iss`, `aud`, `scope`, `exp` and `iat` only, where `iss` is set to "client_email".

Comment: I admit I'm in deep waters here but how do you interpret what's said under "Additional claims" on this page: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: You don't need the `sub` claim for a regular service account. You would need it to impersonate a user.

Comment: Also there's a note on this page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation "Note: Only users with access to the Admin APIs can access the Admin SDK Directory API, therefore your service account needs to impersonate one of those users to access the Admin SDK Directory API." Thanks

Comment: "To impersonate a user" is exactly what I'm struggling with. In the Java example, the GoogleCredential class has this setter setServiceAccountUser(userEmail). I can't find an equivalent property in the ServiceAccountCredentials class in googleapis_auth. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/googleapis_auth/0.2.2/index.html#googleapis_auth/googleapis_auth-auth_io.ServiceAccountCredentials@id_ServiceAccountCredentials-

Comment: I'm afraid you're right: https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth/blob/master/lib/auth.dart#L109 shows that arbitrary claims like `sub` are not parsed, nor does an explicit `sub` parameter exist.

Comment: I'll open an issue here: https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth/issues Thanks for helping :)